# Java web app. Merge audio and video

Tags: java, audio, video, merge

I have two files - audio(mp3 or wav) and video(mp4 or avi) with the same duration. I want to merge them and send to the front.

Which java library will help me to implement that?

Comment: Java Media Framework perhaps (if it still exists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you want to merge the audio and the video on the server side, so that the merged video can then be streamed to the client, then using ffmpeg via a wrapper may be the easiest approach.

The ffmpeg command line is well used and it is quite easy to ask and receive answers to any particular syntax. Using a Java wrapper approach allows you leverage this syntax and give you the flexablity to use other ffmpeg functionality in the future if you need it.

A popular up to date Java Wrapper is available here:

- https://github.com/bramp/ffmpeg-cli-wrapper

If you actually want to stream the audio and the video to the browser separately and do the merging there, then, if you are not worried about an exact match (e.g. needing to synch audio to speech to keep it in lip synch), you can actually just start the audio player and video player simultaneously and the browser will play both together. This worked on all major browsers I tested it on for a project several years ago and I am not aware of anything changing to stop this working.